# Ordinals closed under functions

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $ \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb N \}  $ be a set of functions $f : (\omega_1)^k\to \omega_1 $ where the $k$ is different between functions. Prove that the set of ordinals $\alpha < \omega _1 $ that are closed with respect to all the functions $f_n$, is unbounded and closed.

Answer (score 1):

Show that for a given ordinal $\alpha$, there is only a countable set of possible values all the $f_n$'s can take on $\alpha^n$, take the supremum of these, and reiterate $\omega$ times. Show that the supremum of these $\omega$ ordinals is closed under all the functions.

Use the above technique to show that the set of ordinals which is closed under the functions is unbounded. The closure is simpler, if $\alpha$ is the limit of $\alpha_n$ where each $\alpha_n$ is closed under the functions, then whenever $\vec\beta$ is a $k$-tuple of ordinals below $\alpha$, there is some $\alpha_n$ which bounds them and therefore $f_i(\vec\beta)<\alpha_n<\alpha$.

Comment: This works, but the last part of the hint (intersection of countably many clubs is club) involves another iteration like the one at the end of the answer.  If you change "conclude there possible values $f$ can take $\dots$" to "conclude that the possible values any of the $f_n$'s can take $\dots$", then your argument for one $f$ handles countably many $f_n$'s with essentially no extra work.

Comment: Andreas, you are right of course, about changing it to remove the extra "clubs meet at a club" thing; but I don't understand why there is an extra iteration needed at the end.

Comment: Asaf, the usual proof (really the only proof I know) that the intersection of countably many clubs is unbounded proceeds by taking the supremum of an increasing $\omega$-sequence, obtained by iterating the process "next larger element of the $k$-th club" (where $k$ depends on the stage in the induction, in such a way that every $k$ occurs at infinitely many stages).

Comment: @Andreas, I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Proving that the set of ordinals at which all of the functions are closed is itself closed is very straightforward; the harder part is showing that it’s unbounded. You can do this all at once. Let $\alpha_0<\omega_1$ be arbitrary. Let $\{\langle m_k,n_k\rangle:k\in\omega\}$ be an enumeration of $\omega\times\omega$. Let

$$\alpha_{k+1}=\alpha_k\cup\sup\left\{f_{m_k}(\overline\beta):\overline\beta\in\alpha_k^{r_k}\right\}\;,$$

where $r_k$ is the arity of $f_{m_k}$. Show that $\sup_{k\in\omega}\alpha_k$ is closed under all of the functions.

Comment: Before I start asking questions about your proof, isn't the supremum of a set of ordinals the same as their union?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Yes.

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Isn't that a question about the proof? Congratulation, you have found a contradiction to the axiom of regularity! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I meant that I should probably make sure I have the basics before I ask about the meat of the proof!

Comment: I don't really get the construction of the sequence. How do we know that given any ordinal less than w_1, there is an element of the sequence that is greater than it?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: If you’re talking about the sequence of $\alpha_k$’s, we don’t, because it isn’t true. The point is that no matter what $\alpha_0$ you start with, $\sup_k\alpha_k\ge\alpha_0$, and $\sup_k\alpha_k$ is closed under all of the functions. Thus, the set of ordinals closed under all of the functions is unbounded in $\omega_1$.

Comment: Okay. Regarding the closed part, the definition I have for a subset of $A \subseteq \omega _1$ to be closed is: for every $\delta<\omega _1$ such that $A \cap \delta$ is unbounded in $\delta$, then $\delta \in A$. I'm having difficulty proving closedness of the set (of ordinals at which all of the functions are closed) by this definition. In fact, I don't really see how this definition conforms with the order-topology definition.

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: It’s equivalent to the order-topology definition. If $A\cap\delta$ is unbounded in $\delta$, then $\delta$ is a limit ordinal in the closure of $A\cap\delta$.

Comment: Could you explain "If A∩δ is unbounded in δ, then δ is a limit ordinal in the closure of A∩δ."? What is A∩δ actually, are we treating δ as a set temporarily?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Yes, $\delta=\{\xi:\xi<\delta\}$. If $A\cap\delta$ is unbounded in $\delta$, then for each $\xi<\delta$ there is an $\alpha\in A\cap\delta$ such that $\xi<\alpha$. (If that’s not the definition of unbounded that you’re using, your definition of *closed* is simply wrong.) That implies that $\delta$ is a limit ordinal and that it’s in the closure of $A\cap\delta$ in the order topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: So this definition seems to say that if δ is in the closure of A∩δ, then δ∈A. But why is the intersection with A necessary, isn't the definition "if δ is in the closure of A, then δ∈A" correct?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: If one already knows about the order topology, one can work with that. You’ve been given an equivalent definition that requires only understanding what an ordinal looks like; it doesn’t require any knowledge of topology at all. The two are equivalent, however.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see, thanks.

Comment: I'm going over the solution at the moment and noticed that you never used $n_k$ in the proof, and it seems unnecessary unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: It’s crucial: you need to make sure that each of the functions is applied cofinally often in order to show that $\alpha$ is closed under them.

Comment: I don't understand. It doesn't seem to be used in the construction of the sequence of alphas. Where is it used?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: As I said: in proving that $\alpha$ is closed under all of the functions.

Comment: I proceed to attempt to prove $\alpha$ is closed under all the functions: let $\delta<\alpha$, we need to show that for all n, $f_n(\delta)<\alpha$. We know that there is some $\alpha_k$ such that $\delta<\alpha_k<\alpha$. What now?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: $\delta$ isn’t in the domain of $f_n$ unless $r_n=1$. However, if $\overline\beta$ is in the domain of $f_n$, then there is a $k\in\omega$ such that $\overline\beta\in\alpha_k^{r_n}$. And there is an $\ell\ge k$ such that $m_\ell=n$, so ... ? (Without the $n_k$’s you couldn’t guarantee the existence of such an $\ell$.)

Comment: So we get $f_n(\beta) \in \alpha_{l+1}$ ? I still don't see what role the $n_k$'s play in guaranteeing such an $l$.

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Guaranteeing that there **is** such an $\ell$. If you closed under $f_n$ only once, at stage $n$, you’d have no reason to think that $f(\overline\beta)$ was in $\alpha$ when $\overline\beta\in\alpha^{r_n}\setminus\alpha_n^{r_n}$. You have to keep closing under each of the functions over and over again, so that no matter how late the components of $\overline\beta$ appear (i.e., no matter how big $k$ is), you close under every $f_i$ **after** that stage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So then $f_n(\beta) \in a_{l+1}$ implies $f_n(\beta) \in a$ and we are done?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Yes, now you’ve got it.